# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getCurrentPosition on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)

Tags: flutter, flutter-workmanager, geolocator

```
D/FlutterGeolocator( 2882): Disposing Geolocator services
E/FlutterGeolocator( 2882): Geolocator position updates stopped
D/FlutterGeolocator( 2882): Stopping location service.
I/WM-WorkerWrapper( 2882): Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=dc416b8a-e86b-4976-b078-9e8698ac1399, tags={ be.tramckrijte.workmanager.BackgroundWorker } ]
E/flutter ( 2882): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getCurrentPosition on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)
```

I tried to get current location on background.
I used these packages:

```
workmanager: ^0.4.0
geolocator: ^8.0.0
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@pierre.sabot/how-to-fetch-user-location-in-background-with-flutter-e3494021bdf5)

My code is simple

1.Call back function or static main function

```
//callback function
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    await LocationService.getCurrentLocation();
    print("Native called background task-1: $task");

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

2.init function ( I called these function on initstate)

```
Workmanager().initialize(
        callbackDispatcher,
        isInDebugMode: true,
      );

  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
      "22",
      fetchBackground,
      initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 30),
      frequency: Duration(minutes: 30),
  );
```

3. final function is getcurretlocation

```
class LocationService {
  static getCurrentLocation() async { 
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy:LocationAccuracy.best);
    print(position );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the Android specific implementation when the `executeTask` is run.

```dart
//callback function
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
   if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
     GeolocatorAndroid.registerWith();
   } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
     GeolocatorApple.registerWith();
   } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.linux) {
     GeolocatorLinux.registerWith();
   }

   await LocationService.getCurrentLocation();
    print("Native called background task-1: $task");

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Alternatively if you are running Flutter 2.11+, you can use the new `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized()` method to ensure all packages are registered correctly:

```dart
//callback function
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
   DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

   await LocationService.getCurrentLocation();
    print("Native called background task-1: $task");

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

The problem is that the task is run in a separate isolate which executes without the Flutter engine. Therefore the platform specific implementations (in this case `geolocator_android`) is not registered with the platform interface (`geolocator_platform_interface`) resulting in the `MissingPluginException`.

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1041#issuecomment-1125862107) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98473#issuecomment-1060952450).